# How can I use less temporary tables here to improve processing time?

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a long query written for Oracle SQL developer below where I want one row per student for all the data pulls.  In order to isolate the data I'm using (over using) temporary tables to pull one piece of data, then pulling that data in the initial Select statement.  Problem is, the processing time becomes very slow and/or crashes the system in which it's ulitmately being used.  Can any advise me on how to reduce the number of temp tables while still pulling the correct data onto just one line per student? Thanks.  Here is the query:

````
Select st.schoolID, st.student_number, st.lastfirst, st.grade_level, sat.numscore as SAT, psat.numscore as PSAT, msci.numscore as MStempScience, msoc.numscore as MStempSoc,
t4.failcount, t1.poabs, t1.popre,
round(((t1.popre - (t1.poabs + (case when t2.xtra_att>=0 then t2.xtra_att else 0 end)))/(case when t1.popre <>0 then t1.popre end))*100,1)||'%' as Attendance_Rate,
CASE WHEN round(((t1.popre - (t1.poabs + (case when t2.xtra_att>=0 then t2.xtra_att else 0 end)))/(case when t1.popre <>0 then t1.popre end))*100,1) < 90 then 'YES' else 'NO' end as ChronicAbsence,
CASE WHEN t3.discount > 0 THEN 'YES' ELSE 'NO' END as Supspended,
CASE WHEN smi.flagspeced = 1 THEN 'YES' ELSE 'NO' END as SPECED,
CASE WHEN smi.flaglep = 1 THEN 'YES' ELSE 'NO' END as ELL,
CASE WHEN st.lunchstatus in('F','R') THEN 'YES' ELSE 'NO' END as FRED
from students st
left outer join storedgrades sg on sg.studentID = st.ID
inner join S_MI_STU_GC_X smi on smi.studentsdcid = st.dcid
inner join U_def_ext_students ext on ext.studentsDCID = st.dcid
inner join (select psmd.studentID, sum(periods_absent) as poabs, sum(potential_periods_present) as popre

from ps_membership_defaults psmd
where calendardate between '05-SEP-22' and '09-NOV-22'          
group by studentID
)t1 on t1.studentID = st.ID

left outer join (      
select att.studentID, Sum(Case when  ATT_Code in ('TDY','ETD','WTH') and att.schoolid<25  then .14289  when  ATT_Code in ('TDY','ETD','WTH') and att.schoolid in (28,38,40) then .0278 end) as xtra_att
from Attendance att
INNER JOIN attendance_code attc ON att.ATTENDANCE_CODEID = attc.ID AND att.SCHOOLID = attc.SCHOOLID AND att.YEARID = attc.YEARID
where att.att_date between '05-SEP-22' and '09-NOV-22'  --change to param
group by att.studentID
)t2 on t2.studentID = st.ID 
         
left outer join (
select l.studentID,  sum(Case WHEN l.consequence in ('SPNI', 'SPNO') THEN '1' ELSE '0' END) as discount
from log l
where l.schoolID = 28
and l.discipline_incidentdate between '05-SEP-22' and '09-NOV-22'   
group by l.studentID
)t3 on t3.studentID = st.ID

left outer join (
select st.ID, sum(CASE WHEN (pgf.grade = 'F'  and pgf.finalgradename in ('S1', 'S2') ) then 1 else 0 END) as failcount
from students st
inner join pgfinalgrades pgf on pgf.studentid=st.id
where st.grade_level = 12
and st.enroll_status = 0
and pgf.startdate  >= '05-SEP-22'
and st.schoolID = 28
group by st.ID
 )t4 on t4.ID = st.ID
 
left outer join (
select  st.ID, sts.numscore
from studenttestscore sts
inner join students st on sts.studentID = st.ID
inner join testscore ts on ts.ID = sts.testscoreID 
inner join studenttest stest on stest.id = sts.studenttestid
where ts.id = 105
and ts.testID = 1
and stest.test_date between '01-JAN-22' and '09-NOV-22' 
and st.schoolID = 28
and st.grade_level = 12
)sat on sat.ID = st.ID

left outer join (
select  st.ID, sts.numscore
from studenttestscore sts
inner join students st on sts.studentID = st.ID
inner join testscore ts on ts.ID = sts.testscoreID 
inner join studenttest stest on stest.id = sts.studenttestid
where ts.id = 155 
and ts.testID = 103
and stest.test_date between '01-JAN-22' and '09-NOV-22' 
and st.schoolID = 28
and st.grade_level = 12
)psat on psat.ID = st.ID

left outer join(
select  st.ID, sts.numscore
from studenttestscore sts
inner join students st on sts.studentID = st.ID
inner join testscore ts on ts.ID = sts.testscoreID 
inner join studenttest stest on stest.id = sts.studenttestid
where ts.ID = 53
and ts.testID = 3
and stest.test_date between '01-JAN-22' and '09-NOV-22' 
and st.schoolID = 28
and st.grade_level = 12
)msci on msci.ID = st.ID

left outer join (
select  st.ID, sts.numscore
from studenttestscore sts
inner join students st on sts.studentID = st.ID
inner join testscore ts on ts.ID = sts.testscoreID 
inner join studenttest stest on stest.id = sts.studenttestid
where ts.ID = 54
and ts.testID = 3
and stest.test_date between '01-JAN-22' and '09-NOV-22' 
and st.schoolID = 28
and st.grade_level = 12
)msoc on msoc.ID = st.ID

where st.grade_level = 12
and st.enroll_status = 0
and st.schoolid = 28
group by st.student_number, st.schoolID, st.ID, smi.flagatrisk, st.lastfirst, st.grade_level, t1.poabs, t1.popre, t2.xtra_att, t3.discount, smi.flagspeced, smi.flaglep, st.lunchstatus,  t4.failcount, sat.numscore, psat.numscore, msci.numscore, msoc.numscore
order by st.grade_level, st.lastfirst`

```


I've tried adding the test score tables into the join statements on the inital query and adding a case statement into the intial Select statement(marked with arrows), but then I'm getting multiple rows for each student.  

`Select distinct st.schoolID, st.student_number, st.lastfirst, st.grade_level, 
-->CASE WHEN ts.ID = 53 and ts.testID = 3 and stest.test_date = max(stest.test_date) THEN sts.numscore END as sci,
t4.failcount, t1.poabs, t1.popre,
round(((t1.popre - (t1.poabs + (case when t2.xtra_att>=0 then t2.xtra_att else 0 end)))/(case when t1.popre <>0 then t1.popre end))*100,1)||'%' as Attendance_Rate,
CASE WHEN round(((t1.popre - (t1.poabs + (case when t2.xtra_att>=0 then t2.xtra_att else 0 end)))/(case when t1.popre <>0 then t1.popre end))*100,1) < 90 then 'YES' else 'NO' end as ChronicAbsence,
CASE WHEN t3.discount > 0 THEN 'YES' ELSE 'NO' END as Supspended,
CASE WHEN smi.flagspeced = 1 THEN 'YES' ELSE 'NO' END as SPECED,
CASE WHEN smi.flaglep = 1 THEN 'YES' ELSE 'NO' END as ELL,
CASE WHEN st.lunchstatus in('F','R') THEN 'YES' ELSE 'NO' END as FRED
from students st
left outer join storedgrades sg on sg.studentID = st.ID
inner join S_MI_STU_GC_X smi on smi.studentsdcid = st.dcid
inner join U_def_ext_students ext on ext.studentsDCID = st.dcid
-->inner join studenttestscore sts on sts.studentID = st.ID
-->inner join testscore ts on ts.ID = sts.testscoreID 
-->inner join studenttest stest on stest.id = sts.studenttestid`
````

Comment: Please [edit] the question and give a [MRE] with: the `CREATE TABLE` statements for your tables; the `INSERT` statements for your sample data; an English (not code) description of what you are trying to achieve; and the expected output for that sample data. Trying to reverse engineer code with no description of what it is meant to do is not easy; please make it easy for use an tell us what goes in, what it should do and what should come out.

Comment: Also, if you can make your sample data **minimal** so that the example is representative of what you are trying to achieve but only uses between 1 and 3 tables and a small number of columns then you are more likely to get a higher quality solution (compared to your monster query).

Answer (score 0):

The code is using *inline views* which do not act like temporary tables. The code may benefit from using *common table expressions*, which can act like temporary tables by storing the results once, and the reading those results multiple times.

The references to students are repetitive and can be simplified and possibly optimized by starting the query like this:

```
with students as
(
    select *
    from students st
    where st.schoolID = 28
    and st.grade_level = 12
)
...
```

Another SQL trick that may help simplify and improve performance is conditional aggregation to combine multiple test score queries into one query:

```
...
left join
(
    select  st.ID,
        max(case when (ts.id, ts.testID) in ((105, 1))   then sts.numscore else null end) as sat_score,
        max(case when (ts.id, ts.testID) in ((155, 103)) then sts.numscore else null end) as psat_score,
        max(case when (ts.id, ts.testID) in ((53 , 3))   then sts.numscore else null end) as msci_score,
        max(case when (ts.id, ts.testID) in ((54, 3))    then sts.numscore else null end) as msoc_score,
    from studenttestscore sts
    inner join students st on sts.studentID = st.ID
    inner join testscore ts on ts.ID = sts.testscoreID 
    inner join studenttest stest on stest.id = sts.studenttestid
    where (ts.id, ts.testID) in ((105, 1),(155, 103),(53, 3),(54, 3))
    and ts.testID = 103
    and stest.test_date between '01-JAN-22' and '09-NOV-22' 
    and st.schoolID = 28
    and st.grade_level = 12
    group by st.ID
) student_scores
...
```

Most SQL optimization can be done by cleaning up the code with advanced features. If those changes don't help, then you may want to look into generating execution plans with the actual run times and cardinalities for each operation as described [here](https://oracle-base.com/articles/9i/dbms_xplan#gather_plan_statistics_hint). With those numbers, you can focus on precisely which part of the SQL statement is slow.